# jpa repository with 2 same methods

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying something in JPA Repository to add 2 same method names. I am not sure if it is possible or not.

This is what I am actually trying to do in JPA Interface:

```
public interface TbiDDCustomQueryConfigDao extends CrudRepository<TbiDDCustomQueryConfig, Integer>, JpaRepository<TbiDDCustomQueryConfig, Integer>{

    @Query("select c from TbiDDCustomQueryConfig c, TbiDataSource d where c.datasourceId= d.dataSourceId and c.tbiDDConfigMaster.ddConfigId = ?1 and c.isActive = ?2 and d.isActive='Y'")
    List<TbiDDCustomQueryConfig> findByDdConfigIdAndIsActive(Integer ddConfigId,String isActive);

    TbiDDCustomQueryConfig findByDdConfigIdAndIsActive(Integer ddConfigId,String isActive);

}
```

Compile error told me to rename the method. I changed 2nd method as below:

```
TbiDDCustomQueryConfig findByDdConfigIdAndIsActive1(Integer ddConfigId,String isActive);
```

But when I run the code, I got error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.acinfotech.timebound.jpa.dao.TbiDDCustomQueryConfigDao com.acinfotech.timebound.jpa.service.ReportJobsPersistenceServiceImpl.tbiDDCustomQueryDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tbiDDCustomQueryConfigDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property dd found for type TbiDDCustomQueryConfig!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tbiDDCustomQueryConfigDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property dd found for type TbiDDCustomQueryConfig!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:912)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:770)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property dd found for type TbiDDCustomQueryConfig!
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:359)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:359)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:270)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part.<init>(Part.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$OrPart.<init>(PartTree.java:201)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.buildTree(PartTree.java:291)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree$Predicate.<init>(PartTree.java:271)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.PartTree.<init>(PartTree.java:83)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.PartTreeJpaQuery.<init>(PartTreeJpaQuery.java:57)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:162)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:69)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:304)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:161)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:224)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:210)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    ... 60 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have with the same name taking the same parameters. Java doesn't allow that. If you rename the lower method, which is automatically interpreted by spring-data-jpa, it won't work. The method not annotated with `@Query` is interpreted by its name. Renaming it causes errors like yours, where it can't find the properties. IsActive1 doesn't exist, e.g.

Solution: Rename the upper method and make sure all properties exist in your entity. Specifically because it says:
`No property dd found for type TbiDDCustomQueryConfig!`

You probably want `findByIdAndIsActive` or something along those lines.

Answer (score 7):

The accept answer did not address the issue when we want to have two method with the same name for whatever reasons. (i.e. findById but with different annotations for example.)

According to the spring data jpa document. (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation)

> Any text between find (or other introducing keywords) and By is considered to be descriptive unless using one of the result-limiting keywords such as a Distinct to set a distinct flag on the query to be created or Top/First to limit query results.

You can add text between the `find...By` in your second method name to separate it from the first method while keeping the same functionality.

i.e. `findSomeTextByDdConfigIdAndIsActive`

```java
@Query("select c from TbiDDCustomQueryConfig c, TbiDataSource d where c.datasourceId= d.dataSourceId and c.tbiDDConfigMaster.ddConfigId = ?1 and c.isActive = ?2 and d.isActive='Y'")
List<TbiDDCustomQueryConfig> findByDdConfigIdAndIsActive(Integer ddConfigId,String isActive);

TbiDDCustomQueryConfig findSomeTextByDdConfigIdAndIsActive(Integer ddConfigId,String isActive);
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't think the problem is from the upper

```
findByDdConfigIdAndIsActive (Integer ddConfigId,String isActive);
```

i have the same method

```
findByParentGroupIdIsNullAndDeleted(boolean deleted); //parentGroupId , deleted
```

and it work fine . 
spring data jpa considered 'DdConfigId' as 'dd' so Config is the problem , maybe spring data take 'config' like Keyword expressions same as 'AND' and 'OR'